# R script - nls function

Tags: r, least-squares, nls

Can anyone give me a good explanation for what the parameter "algorithm" does in the nls function in R?

Also, how does the formula work? I know it uses a tilda, but I can't really find a down-to-earth explanation of it.

Also, how important are the start values? Do I need to try multiple start values, or can I still have a guarantee that nls will find the correct parameters regardless of the start values I use?

Comment: As for the algorithm and formula parts, try reading `?nls` carefully and then edit your question to describe, in detail, which parts of the help file are unclear to you.

Comment: There's a 1001 way to skin a cat. `algorithm` defines the way. See `?formula` for info on formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief:
`nls()` is going to vary parameters to try to minimize the square error between your model and your data. There's several good methods it can try to find the minimum. Reading the details about "method" in `?optim` will provide some good info and references.

In general, for nonlinear models, your results can be sensitive to initial guess. You should try several different guesses to make sure that the outputs are close. If your results *are* very sensitive to your guess, you can try re-parameterizing, using a different algorithm, or rethinking your model.

As for the formula, I'd echo the previous answer. Work through the examples in the bottom of `?nls` and then try to ask a more specific question.